# SVN changelist workflow

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

This question could applied to svn in general but specifically I'm using Intellij IDEA.

Currently, if I start a new changelist and make a change to a file in another changelist, it either makes me put the file into the new changelist OR the file in the other changelist will contain the new changes I'm adding.

Is there a way I could make more changes to files that were in the original changelist, but keep the changes I previously made in the old changelist AND also have the new and previous changes in the new changelist?

Answer (score 0):

You can create any number of changelists. The file can be linked only with one changelist.
You can mark selected changelist as default. All new changed files will be stored in default changelist.
And you can move arbitary files beetwen changelists.

Is that enough for you case?

Answer (score 0):

Changelists are "only" a better way to organize your modified files. AFAIK you cannot separate two changes in the same file into two different changelists.